# docker-compose run multiple instances

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Maybe it seems to be a noob question, but I've got script which runs differents jobs.
Each job runs the following command: `docker-compose run --rm my-service`

I'd like to run two jobs at the same time, how can I do this?
Obviously, I tried to run the command in two differents terminals but there's an error that let me think that he's not creating a new container.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `Obviously, I tried to run the command in two differents terminals but there's an error that let me think that he's not creating a new container.` you need to first resolve the error, if it cannot be run same time with two terminals, I think it also impossible to run with compose even compose may have any solutions.

Comment: As I said, the errors lets me think that he's not running a new container (with a new environment). If it can't run the image twice it won't be possible. If you want to know more, my script is using data in database to generate a file. I'd like to get two containers using the same database to generate two different files at the same time